# Cisco AM10 USB wireless adapter not working with Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: wireless, usb, adapter, cisco

I have a Cisco AM10 USB wireless adapter which used to work with 18.4. But after the latest upgrade to 20.04.1 it stopped working. Basically it is recognize as a USB drive but not a wireless hardware. It is not listed in "*lshw -C network*" command output.
Here are some command outputs:

```
ubuntu:~$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 008: ID 1307:1169 Transcend Information, Inc. TS2GJF210 JetFlash 210 2GB

Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1307:0169 Transcend Information, Inc.
```

.

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo lsusb -v

Bus 002 Device 013: ID 1307:1169 Transcend Information, Inc. TS2GJF210 JetFlash 210 2GB

Device Descriptor:

  idVendor           0x1307 Transcend Information, Inc.

  idProduct          0x1169 TS2GJF210 JetFlash 210 2GB

  bcdDevice            1.00

  iManufacturer           1 Cisco Systems, Inc.

  iProduct                5 Cisco AM10 AM10
```

Comment: Please do: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install usb-modeswitch` Reboot and show us a new reading of `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I still cannot use the adapter after running the command and rebooting the computer. Here is the output of lsusb:  

ubuntu:~$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 011: ID 1307:1169 Transcend Information, Inc. TS2GJF210 JetFlash 210 2GB

Bus 002 Device 010: ID 1307:0169 Transcend Information, Inc.

Comment: Please remove the device and run: `tail -f /var/log/syslog`. Insert the device and note the reult. Paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Also, do you have a file `/var/log/usb_modeswitch` ? Are there any clues there?

Comment: I pasted the output of the syslog in the provided link. There is nothing with usb in /var/log.

Comment: After you paste the output, it creates a link that we need to see in order to read the paste. Please give us the link. For example: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RZ2Qj7PRDH/

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/m5QDkWwsF2/

Comment: Also in a paste, let us see: `cat /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules | grep 1307`

Comment: ubuntu:~$ cat /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules | grep 1307
ATTR{idVendor}=="1307", ATTR{idProduct}=="1169", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'"

Comment: It looks normal, perfect and therefore I see nothing fixable. Does it spring to life if you do: `sudo usb_modeswitch -K -v 1307 -p 1169` Check: `dmesg | grep mode`

Comment: I tried. Nothing helps. But thank you for your help. The last think I can try, just buy a new adapter :)

Comment: I regret that I haven't any better suggestions. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my AM10 working on 20.04.3 by running the cisco usb modeswitch:

`sudo usb_modeswitch -L -v 1307 -p 1169`

This fix persists on reboot but disconnecting the adapter requires running the command again. I assume modifying `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules` referenced earlier would make the change permanent.

Comment: We would think so, except that it's already there: # Cisco AM10 "Valet Connector"
ATTR{idVendor}=="1307", ATTR{idProduct}=="1169", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'"
The question is then, why doesn't it just work??